# WPF Data template for Listbox and Context menu

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, material-design-in-xaml

I am trying to make a list with a context menu using a data template.
So far I have the following code:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>                  
    </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <ListBox.Items>
       <sys:String>Item 1</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Item 2</sys:String>
      </ListBox.Items>
</Listbox>
```

I want to add the following context menu:

```
<ContextMenu>
  <MenuItem Header="Edit" />
  <MenuItem Header="Delete" />
</ContextMenu>
```

I have tried using ListBox.ItemContainerStyle and Setter but I am using [Material Design](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML), and when I use a style setter it takes away those material design styles.

Comment: You can set the `BasedOn` property on your style to inherit the material style (if you have a key for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
<ListBox>
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/> 
     </StackPanel>     
     <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
       <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit" />
        <MenuItem Header="Delete" />   
       </ContextMenu>
    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>         
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <ListBox.Items>
   <sys:String>Item 1</sys:String>
   <sys:String>Item 2</sys:String>
  </ListBox.Items>
</Listbox>
```

Or use *BasedOn* property with ListBox.ItemContainerStyle.